# Decrease hours in all Dates in my RestEasy responses

Tags: date, format

I hava some RestEasy controllers, some of them return Dates that i need to set to -3 hours.
I already made a class that format all my dates so they format to ISO8601 and i was wondering if there is any way to set all dates to -3 the same way.
Heres my code of the Dates format:

```
public class JacksonConfig implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper>{
    
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConfig() throws Exception
    {
        objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(
                           SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0)
    {
        return objectMapper;
    }
 }
```

Can i add something to this or some class like this that configure all my dates to -3 hours? Thanks

I tried to do it in the controllers i need but theres a lot of them so im trying to look for a more global solution